# help me find the sound effect

Tags: sound, effect

I hope you could help me, I'm trying to identify the name of the horn sounding sound effect used at 1:39 [

in that video.

Answer (score 0):

Trombone is the first thing that comes to mind but it doesn't sound like a real brass instrument. Try a cheap Plastic Horn. [image]